# Validate columns and write the error message in an additional column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting an error while doing like this:

```
val input = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "\t").schema(trFile).csv(fileNameWithPath)

val newSchema = trFile.add("ERROR_COMMENTS", StringType, true)

// Call you custom validation function
val validateDS = dataSetMap.map { row => validateColumns(row) }    //<== error here

// Reconstruct the DataFrame with additional columns                      
val checkedDf = spark.createDataFrame(validateDS, newSchema)

def validateColumns(row: Row): Row = {
  var err_val: String = null
  val effective_date = row.getAs[String]("date")
  .................

  Row.merge(row, Row(err_val))
}
```

Error message:

```
◾Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._ Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases. 
◾not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$6: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]. Unspecified value parameter evidence$6
```

This is my schema:

```
val FileSchema = StructType(
    Array(
      StructField("date", StringType),
      StructField("count", StringType),
      StructField("name", StringType)
      ))
```

I am new to Spark, let me know, whats the issue here & is there any best way to achieve this. I am using Spark version 2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to use an `UDF` in this situation, then you do not have to be concerned about scehma changes, using `row.getAs`, etc.

First, convert the method into an `UDF` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val validateColumns = udf((date: String, count: String, name: String)){
 // error logic using the 3 column strings
  err_val
}
```

To add the new column to the dataframe, use `withColumn()`,

```
val checkedDf = input.withColumn("ERROR_COMMENTS", validateColumns($"date", $"count", $"name"))
```